# Most concise notation for Pearson's r and Spearman's rho tests

Tags: statistical-significance, pearson-r, spearman-rho, notation

What is the most space-efficient way of denoting the relevant results of significance testing for Pearson's $r$ and Spearman's $\rho$ in a paper when the context is relatively clear and the values serve as extraneous information outside the main body of text (e.g. in a footnote or table)?

The results would accompany a plot of data which visibly shows a trend, but the trend is not very strong, hence my hopes that adding significance testing results as an addendum might be of use for discerning readers. However, the results of these specific tests are not directly related to the main hypothesis of the paper but are useful for understanding the meaning of the main results. Of course, the notation should be conventionalized enough to be understood at a glance or putting it in a footnote would be counter-productive to the flow of the paper.

Comment: Without more context this is hard to answer. If you have a very large sample size then any significance testing is unnecessary. If you publish in health journals then you will probably be asked to give a confidence interval at least for Pearson and if the results are peripheral invited to put them in supplementary material on-line.

Comment: Thanks; that's good to know. The dataset is not massive but is not tiny, and it will be a supplement to a plot which very visibly shows a trend, but the trend is not a very strong one (hence wanting to put the significance as an addendum somewhere).